# Gridview row in editing mode when I press "Insert" button? asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and some control below the griview. I insert values from "control" and press "Insert" button then the values are inserted into the gridview row. Here is the gridview image when I insert values in control 
and press the "Insert" button

[image: image1]

and when I click on the "edit" button in griview the values of the selected edit row are displayed below the "controls" but when I update values in the control and click again "insert" then the row automatically edits the data, but I don't want this, I want that when I click on "insert" again that the row should not display in edit mode, here is the image

[image: image2]

I want that when I click on "insert" button that the row values are replaced with new values.

Here is my **aspx.cs** code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Column Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Data Type", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Allow Null", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Primary Key", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
        Session["MyDataTable"] = dt;
    }
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable t = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];
    DataRow row1 = t.NewRow();
    row1["ID"] = t.Rows.Count + 1;
    row1["Column Name"] = TextBox1.Text;
    row1["Data Type"] = DropDownList1.Text;
    row1["Allow Null"] = Null.Checked == true ? "true" : "false";
    row1["Primary Key"] = Primary.Checked == true ? "true" : "false";
    t.Rows.Add(row1);
    Session["MyDataTable"] = t;
    GridView2.DataSource = t;
    GridView2.DataBind();
    TextBox1.Text = String.Empty;
    DropDownList1.Text = "Select DataType";
}

protected void GridView2_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable t = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];
    t.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
    GridView2.DataSource = t;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable t = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];
    //GridView2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    // TextBox1.Enabled = true;
    //GridViewRow row = GridView2.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
    TextBox1.Text =   GridView2.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
    DropDownList1.Text = GridView2.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[3].Text.ToString();
    GridView2.DataSource = t;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView2_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable t = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];
    GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
    GridViewRow row = GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    GridView2.DataSource = t;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}

public void cancel(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable t = (DataTable)Session["MyDataTable"];
    GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
    GridViewRow row = GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    GridView2.DataSource = t;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: We're going to need to see some underlying code, how are you achieving this? Show us some code from your View, Javascript and Controllers, so we can point you in the right direction

Comment: Kindly check my updated question.Soory,I forget to post code here.But Now I have posted my code.Kindly check and give me response.